# Регулярное выражения на php

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Народ помогите с выражением есть заголовок:

```
content-language:zh-CN
content-length:0
date:Mon, 07 Mar 2016 15:46:25 GMT
location:http://s.taobao.com/search?app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1W6OpLVXXXXbsaXXXXXXXXXXX
s:STATUS_NOT_EXISTED
server:nginx
status:302 Found
strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000
timing-allow-origin:*
version:HTTP/1.1
```

как с этого вырезать этот кусок:

```
TB1W6OpLVXXXXbsaXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст занесен в `$txt`, то попробуйте это:

```
preg_match('/tfsid=(\w+)/s', $txt, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

Comment: результат: null

Comment: curl ответил так: `string(448) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: Tengine Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 16:34:39 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive S: STATUS_NOT_EXISTED Location: http://s.taobao.com/search?app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1CSKtLVXXXXcGXVXXXXXXXXXX Content-Language: zh-CN Set-Cookie: thw=xx; Path=/; Domain=.taobao.com; Expires=Tue, 07-Mar-17 16:34:39 GMT; Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 Timing-Allow-Origin: * "`

Comment: Да нет, функция рабочая... Вот, проверил: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/647dafe4ad0d3b150a6cec4257c20730c5e805bd

Comment: я то тоже проверял все ok но вот проблема в курл`е что ли? `print_r($page);` так header показывает уже так `preg_match('/tfsid=(\w+)/g', $page, $m);print_r($m[1]);` не выводить

Comment: попробуйте поставить не `/g`, а `/s`

Comment: спасибо теперь заработала))

Comment: а, ну прекрасно! `/g` - это в JS.... Запутались :).. Закрываем вопрос (не забудьте галочку поставить)